# Parse the file and get the output

Tags: ruby

I would like to parse the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and get the output of ip address. My file is:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
  # puppet managed
    search eb.com eb.io.com
    nameserver 10.1.21.1
    nameserver 10.1.9.5
    nameserver 10.1.2.29
    nameserver 10.1.5.28
```

It gives the output as:

```
nameserver 10.1.21.1
nameserver 10.1.9.5
nameserver 10.1.2.29
nameserver 10.1.5.28
```

but I need only the ip address in one line.

```
10.1.21.1 10.1.9.5 10.1.2.29 10.1.5.28
```

Can I have someone help me?

Comment: IO.readlines.each { |x| # match regex and put somewhere }

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But i got the output all the stuff from resolv.conf "puppet managed eb.com eb.io.com 10.1.21.1 10.1.9.5 10.1.2.29 10.1.5.28" .But i need only the ip address, can we strip off all other string in the output?

Comment: That's exactly what I said: use a regular expression, that's what they're designed for.

Answer (score 0):

This simple snippet of code should work for you.

For each line in the file we check if is present the word 'nameserver' followed by an ip address.

If it's true we store that ip address into an array, at the end we print out all the addresses joined by a whitespace.

```
ip_addresses = []
File.readlines('/etc/resolv.conf').each do |line|
  match = line.match(/nameserver\W+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/)
  next unless match
  ip_addresses << match[1]
end

puts ip_addresses.join ' '
```